# ListView to Gridview is causing RuntimeException: Your content must have a ListView whose id attribute is 'android.R.id.list'

Tags: android, listview, gridview, android-arrayadapter, retrofit

I have an app that shows a list of images in a ListView when run (see screenshot). Now I want to change GridView (instead of a ListView), I’m getting the above error and I’m not sure how I can fix this. I don’t think it like the method setListAdapter as it only works for a ListView but doesn’t work in a GridView.

Here is the screenshot:

[image]

I’m using retrofit to grab the images from the web.

//here is the bit of the code it doesn’t like:

```
public void success(MoviesResponse moviesresponse, Response response) {
   movieList = moviesresponse.getResults();

   adapter adapt = new adapter(getApplicationContext(),R.layout.item_file,movieList);

   setListAdapter(adapt);

}
```

here is my activity_main:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent" tools:context=".MainActivity">

   <GridView
       xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
       xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="match_parent"
       android:columnWidth="150dp"
       android:numColumns="auto_fit"
       android:verticalSpacing="0dp"
       android:horizontalSpacing="0dp"
       android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
       tools:context=".MainActivityFragment"
       android:id="@+id/gridview_movie">
   </GridView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Here is the stacktrace:

```
 E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                    Process: com.jays.moviesapp, PID: 28134
                                                                    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.jays.moviesapp/com.jays.moviesapp.MainActivity}: java.lang.RuntimeException: Your content must have a ListView whose id attribute is 'android.R.id.list'
                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2184)
                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2233)
                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
                                                                        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5001)
                                                                        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                                                                        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
                                                                        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
                                                                     Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Your content must have a ListView whose id attribute is 'android.R.id.list'
                                                                        at android.app.ListActivity.onContentChanged(ListActivity.java:243)
                                                                        at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:293)
                                                                        at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1929)
                                                                        at com.jays.moviesapp.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:32)
                                                                        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
                                                                        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2148)
                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2233) 
                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135) 
                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196) 
                                                                        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136) 
                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5001) 
                                                                        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
                                                                        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785) 
                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601) 
                                                                        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

UPDATE: Here is the MainActivity and adapter as requested

Here is full MainActivty:

```
public class MainActivity extends ListActivity {




    List<Movie> movieList;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        RestAdapter restAdapter = new RestAdapter.Builder()
                .setEndpoint("http://api.themoviedb.org/3")
                .setRequestInterceptor(new RequestInterceptor() {
                    @Override
                    public void intercept(RequestFacade request) {
                        request.addEncodedQueryParam("sort_by", "popularity.des");
                        request.addEncodedQueryParam("api_key","YOURAPIKEY");
                    }
                })
                .setLogLevel(RestAdapter.LogLevel.FULL)
                .build();

        MovieAPI service = restAdapter.create(MovieAPI.class);

        service.getPopularMovies(new Callback<MoviesResponse>() {
            @Override
            public void success(MoviesResponse moviesresponse, Response response) {
                movieList = moviesresponse.getResults();

                movieList = moviesresponse.getResults();

                adapter adapt = new adapter(getApplicationContext(),R.layout.item_file,movieList);

                setListAdapter(adapt);
            }

            @Override
            public void failure(RetrofitError error) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });


    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);

        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Comment: maybe the problem is on the Adapter class...can you post it?

Comment: post complete activity code and adapter class

Comment: setListAdapter(adapt); shows that you are using ListActivity.To use GridView you have to use Activity instead of ListActivity

Comment: HI vspallas and bhargav thanks for responding. I updated my post to include MainAcivity and adapter class

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you are using `ListActivity`, ie. your Activity extends `ListActivity`, so using a `GridView` won't work.

Instead, you should use a normal Activity, and then use the GridView from your layout.

Something like this in your `onCreate` should do the trick:

```
setContentView(R.layout.main);
GridView mGridView = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridview_movie);

adapter adapt = new adapter(getApplicationContext(),R.layout.item_file, movieList);
mGridView.setAdapter(adapt);
```

Comment: I tried that but I'm getting this error: Error:(54, 33) error: constructor adapter in class adapter cannot be applied to given types;
required: Context,int,List<Movie>
found: Context,int,GridView
reason: actual argument GridView cannot be converted to List<Movie> by method invocation conversion

Comment: @D.Ace, I have updated my answer according to the code you posted, you need to do `adapter adapt = new adapter(getApplicationContext(), R.layout.item_file, movieList)` in your `getPopularMovies`, and it should work.

Answer (score 0):

Simply use 
`android:id="@android:id/list"`
and use `android.R.id.list` to refer to your GridView.

Comment: Hi Parham, I forgot to say I already changed my gridview to use t android:id="@android:id/list"  but Im still getting the exact error